# Cocoa View Controller Scene issue

Tags: xcode, cocoa

[image: image1]  [image: image2]I have 2 View Controller Scenes. Scene2 holds settings that will be used in scene1. Scene2 is accessed by menu item and its presented as show.

Now the issue is that the settings used in scene2 will not be used by scene1 unless the latter is refreshed.

I did try to trigger a viewDidLoad() of scene1 when the settings were saved at scene2 but it crashed.

```
   class replaceSegue: NSStoryboardSegue {


    override func perform() {
        if let fromViewController = sourceController as? NSViewController {
            if let toViewController = destinationController as? NSViewController {
                // no animation.
                fromViewController.view.window?.contentViewController = toViewController
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: It's hard to guess just from a high-level description, but....  Does scene1's `viewWillAppear` get called when scene2 is dismissed?  Do you (or can you) use an unwind segue?  How about notifying scene1 when there are settings changes (possibly via a data model)?

Comment: I have uploaded two screenshots to give you a better understanding, as you can see its not as if it goes from scene1 to scene2, scene2 is linked to a menu item and opens next to scene1. I have tried tried calling viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad of scene1 from scene2 but throws optional unwrapping error! I thought about unwind segue but considering the setup it wouldnt do anything right? Any thoughts?

Comment: Two functions that are held in viewDidLoad of scene one is to check if multiplier has been saved in scene2 to disable the multiplier textfield of scene one and change the label to the multiplier saved

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking about separate windows.  (I've been using a custom segue to keep view controllers inside a single window.)  For what you're doing, I think I'd create a separate class (singleton) to save the settings and have it fire a NSNotification whenever a settings value changed.  Scene1 would be a listener and do what it needed when receiving the notification.

Comment: I tried that too, i wanted if  the "save multiplier button" was pressed to perform custom segue from scene1 to scene2 but didnt work.. i will add to the description the class of my custom segue