# Cocoa segue setup issues

Tags: xcode, cocoa, segue

On the same ViewController i have one segue triggered programatically only if condition is met, and another one that i would like it to be performed if a button is pressed independantly of condition met or not.

The second segue is not performed saying that the condition isnt met
The first segue has identifier "segue" and this is how its triggered programatically:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {

    if condition==true{
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }

override  func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if  (segue.identifier=="segue"){

        (segue.destinationController as! NSViewController).representedObject=someString

    }

}

}
```

The second segue has identifier "segue2" and its connected from the button to the destination view controller.

How can i get the segue2 to be performed independantly of the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you should compare the identifier and always return true if it matches the second segue name.  Only check the condition if the identifier matches the first segue name.

Comment: Thanks Phillips, could you please explain to me something? I have the same setup on iOS, only difference is that the button linked to the segue2 is on the NavigationBar, and it works fine without implementing your suggestion...

Comment: I can only guess but if segue2's button doesn't belong to the same view controller, then `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` would not be called.  A breakpoint should tell you the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, in both cases the buttons belong to the same ViewController.. This solution i implemented is an alternative, in my original design i stamped on another issue , was banging my head against the wall for a day couldnt solve it, i am not very familiar with the rules here and i apologise in advance if i am out of line but would it be too much to ask for your help on the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734559/cocoa-view-controller-scene-issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you should link the button to an IBAction that programmatically performs the segue. Also, move the logic of checking the condition to another function that you call somewhere in your view controller.

```
@IBAction buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue2", sender: self)
}

func checkCondition() {

    if condition == true {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: self)
    }
}

override  func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if  (segue.identifier=="segue") {
        (segue.destinationController as! NSViewController).representedObject=someString
    }
    else if  (segue.identifier=="segue2") {
        // Do any segue 2 setup
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shades, thank you for taking the time to provide an answer, i only chose Phillip's answer because is shorter to implement, but yours is as good!